# Is there a way to mimic ctrl+alt+tab functionality with WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp

I'm looking for a way to add a preview of currently active windows (using their window handler) with images and live updates.
Similar to Windows ctrl+alt+tab which basically streams all the active windows or shows a cached version of the non-active windows.

Is there a way to achieve that using WPF? should I use another UI framework for such a requirement?

At the moment I found a way to screenshot an active non-focused window using user32 api -

```cs
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hDC, uint nFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr handle, ref Rectangle rect);


var _clientHandler = Process.GetProcessesByName(PROCESSNAME)[0].MainWindowHandle;

CaptureWindow(_clientHandler);


void CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
{
    // Get the size of the window to capture
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);

    // GetWindowRect returns Top/Left and Bottom/Right, so fix it
    rect.Width = rect.Width - rect.X;
    rect.Height = rect.Height - rect.Y;

    // Create a bitmap to draw the capture into
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height))
    {
        // Use PrintWindow to draw the window into our bitmap
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
            if (!PrintWindow(handle, hdc, 0))
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                var exception = new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(error);
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + error + ": " + exception.Message);
                // TODO: Throw the exception?
            }
            g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
        }

        // Save it as a .png just to demo this
        bitmap.Save("Example.png");
    }
}
```

I guess I can repeat that process for each window 30 times a second (or with w/e fps I'll want).
Would that be the correct approach? is there a better way to achieve that?

I'll appreciate any guidance, ty.

Comment: 30 fps? I doubt it'll be that fast. Getting screenshots is quite slow, and some windows may even appear black.

Comment: The logic above worked with 30fps.
That being said, I've eventually opted for the new way of capturing a screen using WinRT, as linked in my answer to this topic.
Which basically gets a callback for every new frame received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinRT has provided a new set of APIs that can achieve exactly that -
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/

A repo example that implements screen capture in WPF -
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WPF/ScreenCapture

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer. Could you include the most relevant things of the linked articles? Like the API name or a [mre]?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I mean. the second link is an actual repo (code sample) of the exact question asked (by me btw).